# Adding a variable to a path

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a path, i need to include variables in between that path as shown below

```js
import os

platform = "ppc"
variant = "red"
A2L = "\frdcc_hyb_sw\hn1\output\hn1_" +platform+ "_sil\r" + variant
print A2L
```

i get a weird output as shown below

```js
C:\app\Tools\exam\Python25>python new.py
redcc_hyb_sw\hn1\output\hn1_ppc_sil
```

Comment: Can you please turn this into a question? :-)

Comment: hah sorry i need to get a path as \frdcc_hyb_sw\hn1\output\hn1_ppc_sil\red. According to me i have done it correct, i have no idea why is it acting starge. can you please help with my weird output

Comment: I don't know python, but could that `\r` be interpreted as "carriage return"? Maybe you need to escape backslashes.

Comment: Also, when you have additional info, please edit it into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of [escape characters](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) use it like so (Look also for the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) example which is best practice), If you want the charecter to be escaped like `\n` for new line then just leave it as `\n` instead of `\\n`

**In Short:**

`\n` in string  == new line

`\\n` in string == the notes "\n"

**Code:**

```
platform = "ppc"
variant = "red"
A2L = "\\frdcc_hyb_sw\\hn1\\output\\hn1_" +platform+ "_sil\\r" + variant
print A2L

A2L = "\\frdcc_hyb_sw\\hn1\\output\\hn1_{}_sil\\r{}".format(platform, variant)
print A2L
```

**Output:**

```
\frdcc_hyb_sw\hn1\output\hn1_ppc_sil\rred
\frdcc_hyb_sw\hn1\output\hn1_ppc_sil\rred
```

Comment: how do i make it if it's somthng like "c:\abc\red\gfd\afd\"

Comment: For path use `os.path.join('my', 'path', 'to', 'join')`